# QFile is not allowed to change permissions for the file

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I create QFile and set up permissions like this:

```
/*Reading information to file*/
file.setPermissions(QFile::ReadOwner | QFile::ReadOther | QFile::ReadGroup | QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::WriteOther | QFile::WriteGroup)
file.close()
```

Than I make this file as a resources file and connect it to my project. But something like this:

```
QFile file{ R"(:/text/TextInformation/Matters)" };
qDebug() << file.permissions() << '\n';
```

give me such output:

```
QFlags(0x4|0x40|0x400|0x4000)
```

Another problem: if I try to change permissions now, I getting failed.
In propeties to my resource file I allow to read it and to write on it. How can I change the permissions now (or how can open this file in QFile::WriteOnly mode)?

Comment: We could write the program to set the attributes to the file but the OS still may not allow. What file is there? Is it resource file, btw? Then it is not really even OS file.

Comment: You can not modify a resource - it's read-only.

Comment: @chehrlic. can you write your comment as the answer, please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying resources compiled into the executable is not possible - if you want to modify such a file you have to write it out the the filesystem and modify it there.